# YouTube's iframe not allowing a video to play without going directly to YouTube

Tags: iframe, youtube

I'm building my site around my video editing work. I'm uploading my stuff to YouTube, setting them all to "unlisted" with no monetiziation.

Some videos are playing fine with YouTube's iframe code. Some are telling me "Video Unavailable - Watch on YouTube."

I've tried a few iframe code's I've found across Stack Overflow, using those gives me "YouTube refused to connect."

I've also tried adding in "controls = 0" and "modestbranding=0" to the iframe which gives me "An error occurred. Please try again later."

I've uploaded these videos using the same settings for each. I'm just trying to get them to play directly on my site from YouTube.

As a backup I can play them directly from the folder I think? Although that will depend on the user's internet.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**.

Answer (score 1):

Set referrerPolicy="origin" in the iframe, seems there are  issues with YouTube not getting referrer and blocking videos from serving on a website. Videos might still not work on localhost, but should work when deployed to the real website.

Comment: That did not work for me.